# Why is this data not being passed from jQuery AJAX post to ASP.Net MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I have code that I pass from jQuery to my ASP.Net MVC controller and it works fine. I am now trying to replicate the same functionality in a new situation and the parameter shows up as `null` when I put a breakpoint in my controller code.

Can anyone see anything wrong with the code below. In firebug I see that `calendarIds` is a perfectly populated array but it shows up as null on the server side.

Here is my jQuery code:

```
var calendarIds = [];

$('#box2View option').each(function () {
    calendarIds.push($(this).val());
});

$.post(
    '/EventCalendar/UpdateVisibleCalendars/', 
    { calendarIds: calendarIds }, 
    function (data) {
        //do some callback stuff here (not relevant for question)
    }, 
    "html"
);
```

Here is my controller code

```
public ActionResult UpdateVisibleCalendars(int[] calendarIds)
{
    // right here i check calendarIds and its always NULL :(
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps because you will post `calendarIds=1,2,3,4,5` where as it is expecting `calendarIds=1&calendarIds=2&calendarIds=3...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) which allows you to set the `traditional` flag to true:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/EventCalendar/UpdateVisibleCalendars/',
    type: 'POST',
    traditional: true,
    data: { calendarIds: calendarIds },
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function (data) {

    }
});
```

Now the POST body will look like this:

`calendarIds=1&calendarIds=2&calendarIds=3`

With `tgraditional=false` (which is the default starting from jQuery 1.4) the POST body looks like this:

`calendarIds[]=1&calendarIds[]=2&calendarIds[]=3`

And by consulting [this blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) you will understand that only the first is compatible with the default model binder.

The jQuery's `traditional` flag is well explained in the [`$.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) section.

Comment: yup . . i now see that jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true; was set in my working use case . .i knew there had to be something silly . .

Comment: @leora, yeap, that's why you should should always look at your js debugging tool (FireBug, Chrome Developer Tools, ...) what exactly is posted to the server during the AJAX request. Things like this are becoming immediately obvious.